# iOS9 Enterprise App Distribution

Tags: ipad, ios9, jailbreak, software-distribution, internals

Hopefully this question makes sense to you because I'm pretty frustrated by it right now. My team releases Enterprise-signed apps to customers very manually. No iTunes store or MDM involved. Through iOS8.4.1 this worked just fine. However, in iOS9, APPL introduced a new Verify step for each app distributed this way that checks in with https://ppq.apple.com/v1/authorization as seen in https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204460. That Verify step is annoying for some, but impossible to do for users that aren't permitted to connect to the Internet.

Falling down the rabbit hole at home, I have been looking at the following files on a rooted device:

- /Library/MobileDevice/Indeterminates.plist
- /usr/libexec/online-auth-agent
- /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_arm64 -> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
- /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/SoftwareUpdateServices.log.*

It seems like they are somehow related because the files change when performing the Verify check, but I can only assume I'm missing some aspect of it. (And the binaries are the ones with references to the files that changed.) Looking at the arm64 dumps of online-auth-agent and libmis.dylib haven't been very fruitful because I'm pretty much limited to TextPad and strings here. I have tried:

- clearing out the contents of /Library/MobileDevice/Indeterminates.plist by using plutil -convert xml1
- creating /Library/MobileDevice/AuthListReadyCdHashes.plist with various array of string values that *should* be the app's cdhash value as seen in the Indeterminates.plist

Mucking with those files seemed to only be able to have a negative impact on the Verified state or Settings stability.

Thank you for any help/insight!

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?